# Now that the SE is in public does it make sense to push questions at G+ to answers here?

Tags: support

I'm wondering if it would be in bad form to answer G+ questions here, and then respond in G+ with a link to the SE thread?

Basically, does it now make sense to attempt to redirect the G+ participants over here, and if so how best to do that?

Will it hurt the Craft community to have fragmented support areas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I think it would be good to encourage Google+ users to ask questions here on Stack Exchange instead. For two reasons:

1. Stack Exchange is a *much* better platform for Q&A and findable content (and I don't think I am alone in this sentiment). G+ will just dilute the knowledge base.
2. The Stack Exchange beta site needs participants if it is going to thrive. See the statistics on users for [this site in Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/69388/) to get an idea what's needed.

That said, Stack Exchange isn't a good fit for every type of question (see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)), so having a venue for asking and discussing more open-ended, opinion-based, or poll-type questions would be beneficial. Maybe G+ fills *that* role for now. And then any users asking answerable technical questions on G+ can be encouraged to re-post *those* on Stack Exchange.

As for *how* to move the question from G+ to SE, I think it best to ask the user to re-post the question on their own (rather than re-post it for them). This way the user base grows and they get a chance to become familiar with Stack Exchange if they aren't already.

Comment: That’s what I’ve been doing, e.g. https://plus.google.com/115846957239043983170/posts/4682cwE1Upe :)

Comment: +1 for this: "I think it best to ask the user to re-post the question on their own (rather than re-post it for them). This way the user base grows and they get a chance to become familiar with Stack Exchange if they aren't already."